# Issues in running virtual threads program on intellij with java19

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, project-loom, java-19

I am trying to run below simple program with virtual threads on my intellij with java19 version selected.

### Code

```
public class VTSimple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = () -> System.out.println("Inside Runnable");
        Thread.startVirtualThread(runnable);
    }
}
```

#### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.java19</groupId>
    <artifactId>java19-explore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

### Project Settings

SDK - `19`

Language Level - `X Experimental Features as last version shown was` 17(preview) `in Language Level dropdown` Also Tried `SDK Default` Option as well.

### Error

When I ran the program it gave me below error

```
java: invalid source release 18 with --enable-preview
  (preview language features are only supported for release 19)
```

### Few Trials

I tried to add `--enable-preview` in VM Options of this small program and as well as compiler settings in preferences but it didn't work.

#### Edit 1

[image: intellij compiler preferences]

### Setup Details :

`Mac OS Air M1 : 12.1 Monterey`

Intellij Version : `IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 (Community Edition) Build #IC-213.7172.25, built on March 15, 2022`

Java Version : `openjdk 19.0.1 2022-10-18`

`OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)`

`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)`

### Edit 2

Updated Intellij to version `IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Community Edition)` and java version 19 was showing in language level.
But still there is an error

```
java: ofVirtual() is a preview API and is disabled by default.
  (use --enable-preview to enable preview APIs)
```

Note : I have already passed `--enable-preview` in VM Options of program and Compiler settings in preferences.

Comment: Came across this supported java version in IntelliJ article where Java 18 is the latest version that is supported using IntelliJ 2022.x https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/supported-java-versions.html

Comment: Please show: `well as compiler settings in preferences but it didn't work.` what does that mean? How have you done that?

Comment: Added compiler settings @khmarbaise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2 or newer for Java 19 support.

Comment: Thanks and I have updated the question after updating Intellij Version and there is an issue still.

Answer (score 0):

**--enable-preview** should be in **VM options**, NOT  **program arguments**

[image]

You still need to have those settings in Java Compiler

[image]

And the project settings:

[image]

Also, you can run from the command line

```
java --enable-preview --source 19 Main.java
```

Sample code:

[image]

with the following results:

[image]